# can't find some images in browser online.

Tags: html, image

I have a problem I really can't solve.

When I am testing my website locally on my computer in a browser, all my images are found. When I put the images on the server, some images aren't found anymore.

Example:

http://anneliessuyker.nl/portfolio.html

There are supposed to be two images:

The one "camerablok" isn't found. It's in the exact same directory as "computerblok3", and correct on the server.

When I inspect the image, I finally get this message:

```
*Not Found
The requested URL /images/camerablok.jpg was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2 Server at anneliessuyker.nl Port 80*
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? There are more examples like this on my website. It seems to be really random, when pictures are, or aren't found on the server. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have named your images correctly? - I took a guess and changed the image source to `/images/camera.jpg` and it works fine.

You should think about using a naming convention in order to keep all your files readable and avoid erros like these.

Comment: There is a simular picture called camera on the server as well, this one has a different lay out. Do you think that's the problem? That there are too many simular names or something? How does that work?

Comment: The picture you found is on the page "wat kan ik voor je doen"

Comment: Noted, I have removed the screenshot. could you have accidentally saved this file as a different file type? easily done. Resave, rename and relink the image.

Comment: I checked that as well. It is not just this image, there are more images that aren't found, while there on the server. It is possible it has to do something with apache/2 server port 80 ??

Comment: I doubt it - contact your hosting provider if you think it's server related.

Comment: Provider says it isn't server related.

Comment: alright, i renamed some images, and that works. But still it seems really random to me, which pictures are showed and which are not. So now its just trial and error.. Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by doing development on Windows (with a case insensitive file system) and hosting on Linux (with a case sensitive file system).

Windows doesn't care if a file is called "Foo.jpeg" but you asked for "foo.jpeg".

Linux does.

Check the case of your file names.

Comment: Thanks. I already checked this, and there are no capitals used in my file names. So that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: I renamed a few pictures. And that works. But still it seems really random to me, which pictures are showed, and which aren't. Now it's just trial and error..